# Class involving functions & if/else if statements

Tags: c++, function

The assignment is to write a program that will allow the user to calculate the area and volume of various shapes. Not allowed to use any global variables with the one exception for `PI`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Functions
void showMenu(int &);
double area (double, double);
double area (double);
double volume (double, double, double);
double volume (double);

int main()
{
   int choice;
   double area, volume;
   const double PI = 3.14;

   do
   {
       showMenu();
       cin >> choice;

       if (choice < 1 || choice > 5 )
       {
        cout << "Please select a valid choice of 1-5: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
       }
    else if (choice == 1)
    {

        area = double area (double length, double width);
        cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << endl;

    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {

        area = double area (double radius);
        cout << "The area of the circle is: " << endl;

    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {

        volume = double volume (double length, double width, double height);
        cout << "The volume for a box is: " << endl;

    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {

        volume = double volume (double radius);
        cout << "The volume of a sphere is: " << endl;

    }
}
    while (choice != 5);
return 0;
}


void ShowMenu(int &choice)
{
cout << "1. Calculate the area of a rectangle";
cout << "2. Calculate the area of a circle";
cout << "3. Calculate the volume for a box";
cout << "4. Calculate the volume of a sphere";
cout << "5. Quit";
}

double area (double length, double width);
{
cout << "Enter the length: ";
cin >> length;
cout << "Enter the width: ";
cin >> width;
area = lenght * width;
}

double area (double radius);
{
cout << "Enter the radius: ";
cin >> radius;
area = PI * (radius * 2);
}

double volume (double length, double width, double height);
{
cout << "Enter the length: ";
cin >> length;
cout << "Enter the width: ";
cin >> width;
cout << "Enter the height: ";
cin >> height;
volume = length * width * height;
} 

double volume (double radius);
{
cout << "Enter the radius: ";
cin >> radius;
volume = (4/3) * PI * (radius * 3)
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(20): error C2660: 'showMenu' : function does not take 0 arguments
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(31): error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(38): error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(45): error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(52): error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(71): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(80): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(87): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\labfour.cpp(98): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>  Lab4.cpp
>   1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\lab4.cpp(117): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
>
> 1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab4\lab4\lab4.cpp(127): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: You should go to office hours.

Comment: The errors are pretty self explanatory, just examine the statement on the specified line number for the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correcting compile time errors is not a hard task. Follow error messages and try to find out the problem. I will show you some examples in your code to solve errors. Your code has many error which shows you need practice more in C++.

The declaration of `showMenu` is `void showMenu(int &)` but you are calling it by `showMenu()`:

```
void showMenu(int &);
              ^^^^^
                Remove it
```

Also, to call a function you shall not pass types:

```
area = double area (double length, double width);
       ^^^^^^              ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
```

More, when implementing a function, you shall not put `;` after function signature:

```
double area (double radius); <--- remove semicolon
{
```

Comment: The value passed into `showMenu` doesn't affect the function at all ;) Of course that doesnt affect the validity of your answer, but still you could just cut that `int` from the function signature

Comment: I suspect that the initial intent was that showMenu() should actually obtain the choice too, so the cin >> choice; should have been in the showMenu() function.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Fix most of the errors but still have some.

Answer (score 2):

- This is wrong:

  ```
  area = double area (double length, double width);
  ```

  You're returning the value from `area()`, not declaring it.  Just call the function:

  ```
  area = area(double length, double width);
  ```
- Your calculation in `area(double radius)` is incorrect:

  ```
  area = PI * (radius * 2);
  ```

  That is calculating the circumference.  You should be calculating the area:

  ```
  area = PI * (radius * radius);
  ```

  I don't see how `PI` is recognized in that function.  It's initialized in `main()`, but not passed to the function or put in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an semicolon after:

```
volume = (4/3) * PI * (radius * 3)
```

Function declaration is wrong:

```
double area (double radius);
{
```

Should be (without semicolon)

```
double area (double radius) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Fix most of the errors but still have some.